# Kill process with timeout

Tags: shell

I want to start a programm with timeout, how can I kill the process using SIGINT and SIGKILL? If the programm not terminate within 5 seconds,
send SIGINT. If it’s still running after 10 seconds (in total), send SIGKILL.

I already did timeout -s SIGINT nano; timeout -s SIGKILL nano
but its not working, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4):

The timeout command has a duration option that you are not using.

Per the manual:

> timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...

Anyway, the construct you are using won't work. (e.g. using two separate commands).

I actually recommend using the timelimit command which is far more consistent. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install timelimit
```

From the manual:

> timelimit [-pq] [-S killsig] [-s warnsig] [-T killtime] [-t warntime]
> command [arguments ...]

Links:

man timelimit

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/timelimit.1.html

A actual example of usage from a script of mine is:

```
timelimit -q -t1 -T30 command
```