# How do i limit the amount of time a python script runs

Tags: linux, python

So i use a python scrips that sometimes on some ips it just hangs. I run the script on about 250 ips. With xargs from a sh script

How would i i limit the time of the py script runing. If it hang for more than 30 sec for example to leave/kill ?

I dont want to use time as it is server dependant.
I was thinking more of a python function

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254457/kill-process-with-timeout

Comment: I want to limit the amount of food I eat, but I don’t want to monitor my food intake.  What?  If you don’t want to “use time”,  what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/path/to/job.py &
pid=$!
sleep 30
if kill -0 $pid; then kill -TERM $pid; fi
```